# Create different mysql connections using Navicat

Tags: mysql, connection, navicat

I have many db's from customers and many own db's, all of them in mysql and I'd like to have different mysql connections (Customers, Own).

My trouble is I can't. When I create a second mysql connection, is taking all db I got in my localhost.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Navicat but I have been using [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog), where you can have separate connection for each database.
In SQLYog while creating new connection it ask me for database also, along with other details such as username,password etc.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll try it!